# Using QueryByAttribute cannot retrieve null values

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM Development. I would like to update the custom field values in addtion to its existing values in the CRM 2011 from my C# application. If the field has some values then it is working fine, but if it null then i am receiving "The given key was not present in the dictionary." error.

The code below is what i am trying to achieve.

```
IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;
QueryByAttribute querybyattribute = new QueryByAttribute("salesorder");
querybyattribute.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new String[] {
  "salesorderid", "new_customefield" });

querybyattribute.Attributes.AddRange("ordernumber");
querybyattribute.Values.AddRange(ordernumber);
EntityCollection retrieved = service.RetrieveMultiple(querybyattribute);

foreach (var c in retrieved.Entities)
{
  OrderID = new Guid(c.Attributes["salesorderid"].ToString());
  CustomFieldValue = c.Attributes["new_customefield"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Mr.Konrad, Thank you very much for your quick response. I have used CustomFieldValue = c.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_customfield")
and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because a field with no entered value won't get returned in the context object not the image. Or to put it graspably - you need to check whether a field is amongst the attributes.

It's not sufficient to have declared it and requested it via *ColumnSet*. It's confusing and annoying (been there myself).

Just of the top of my head, I can think of the following code snippet to manage the issue (without having to set an *if* clause for every read but also avoiding a bunch of methods - one for each variable type).

```
private Generic GetEntityValue<Generic>(
  Entity entity, String field, Generic substitute = default(Generic))
{
  if (entity.Contains(field))
    return (Generic)entity[field];
  return substitute;
}
```

edit: Or as an extension method

```
public static T GetAttributeValue<T> (this Entity e, string propertyName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    if (e.Contains(propertyName))
    {
        return (T)e[propertyName];
    }
    else
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, just FYI Entity comes with that method as an ExtensionMethod out of the box http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx

Comment: @glosrob Correct. Very good point! I prefer to use mine because of the default value I can specify (which is very useful when working with *String* class - *n/a* instead of *null* is much less confusing to a non-technical user). Perhaps I should have provided the code to create an extension method to that extension method. Care to edit my most and add it? ;)