# How to update a deployed plugin in Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm new to programming in Dynamics CRM Online and I'm having a problem updating a deployed plugin. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 as my IDE. I deployed a plugin that I need to modify and when I re-deploy it thru VS the modified date in CRM is correct but the changes are not there. Here is my code..

```csharp
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") 
  && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
  Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
  if (entity.LogicalName == "lead")
  {
    if (entity.Attributes.Contains("companyname") == true)
    {
      if (entity["firstname"].ToString() != "null")
        firstName = entity["firstname"].ToString();
      else
        firstName = "";

      if (entity["lastname"].ToString() != "null")
        lastName = entity["lastName"].ToString();
      else
        lastName = "";

      entity["companyName"] = "This is a test";
      //entity["companyname"] = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    else
      throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
        "The company name can only be set by the system.");
  }
}
```

When I create a lead the company name is not "This is a test". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You detect whether the field with company name exists by:

```csharp
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("companyname") == true)
```

but you write to an other, namely:

```csharp
entity["companyName"] = "This is a test";
```

The value is put in the entity but since it has no counterpart in the metadata, it's not being stored. Set the field name to it's to schema name, i.e. lower cased.

---

A few other things to consider in case you get additional errors.

- You need to call *Update* method on the service after you've set the field's value.
- The field should have some kind of prefix (e.g. *new_something*, *beep_something*).
- The camel casing is not applicable here (schema name is), so go *alltolowercase*.

What **do** you get as the company name? Do you get the exception being thrown?

---

Also, some pointers on the code quality. I've rebuilt the logic to eliminate unnecessary complexity of scopes. I removed the superfluous *else* statement and comparisons to *true*. I'd also recommend that you split the process into different methods but I'm sure you've got that covered already. And you might want to use an auxiliary method to obtain the values from the fields. See [in this post at my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088408/using-querybyattribute-cannot-retreive-null-values/15088968#15088968).

```csharp
if (!context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") ||
  context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
  return;

Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
if (entity.LogicalName != "lead")
  return;
if (!entity.Attributes.Contains("companyname"))
  throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
    "The company name can only be set by the system.");

String firstName = String.Empty;
if (entity.Contains("firstname"))
  firstName = entity["firstname"] as String;

String lastName = String.Empty;
if (entity.Contains("lastname"))
  lastName = entity["lastname"] as String;

entity["companyname"] = "This is a test";
//entity["companyname"] = firstName + " " + lastName;
```

EDIT:

If you still don't get the requested behavior, try the following. (I'm not sure on what level of expertise you are so olease accept my apology if you feel insulted by me mentioning some very basic stuff you've already tried a gazillion times.)

Technical tricks.

1. Publish all customizations (I do it **very** often, just in case).
2. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload.
3. Login/logout.
4. Reboot IIS (if on-premise).
5. Unregister the plug in, see if the behavior remains. **Then** re-register it.
6. Check for forgotten workflows running.

There might be some delays and lags. Once, I actually had both the old old and the new version of a plugin being fired, depending on whether I created a record from *Settings* or *Workplace*. That was weird but resolved itself after a few hours. Seriously. **That** was weird!

Programmatic tricks.

1. Check if there are other plugins you might have forgotten to deactivate.
2. Remove all the leads and make sure that the plugin fires upon the new one being created.
3. Change the text to e.g. *I'm a giant moose*, just to make sure that the change goes through.
4. Slash away all code (or place *return* in the beginning of *Execute*. Then, move it down step by step to detect when the weirdness commences.

Of what you've shown, it should work so either you didn't mention something relevant (we **do** appreciated that you didn't post 100000 lines of code, of course) or it's CRM that's weirding off (which is equally annoying and confusing). So, let's trouble-shoot this thing. What happens when you try the tricks above?

As for the code stub, yeah - I'm not too proud of MS effort there. Try to post that code under the tag C# on *Programmers* for code review. Be prepared for an angry discussion. :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the attribute name as it was a typo but it didn't make a difference. If you look at the commented out statement, if I change the last name what I get is "null lastname". The change I was trying to make was to eliminate the "null" (the first name is empty). I expect the instance to be updated by whoever is creating the lead.

Comment: @Gary You're on the way to success soon. Check my edit. My bad - I actually repeated your typo, too. :)

Comment: Much of what you eliminated was what Visual Studio created as a stub, it was nice to see another way to do it, but it didn't change anything. I still end up with "null lastname" not "This is a test"

Comment: Do you have to publish the form after re-deploying the plugin? Thanks

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. I'd like you to test the following to narrow down the root cause of the problem. (See my edit in the reply...)

Comment: Thanks for the help Konrad!! The technical tricks I tried and they didn't make a difference. I'll try the other coding ideas and let you know. I don't have any other plugins, this is my first one. I'm not sure what you mean by removing all of the existing leads? How do I know that plugin fires?

Comment: Strange things are happening. I deleted all existing leads. I then added a new lead and nothing was being filled in in the company name field, but after I saved it there are now 4 more leads all with the name John Doe. I'm on a trial system and I'm wondering what else could be triggering.

Comment: After taking a closer look, it actually creates a new lead about every 10-15 seconds. If I unregister the plugin it stops.

Comment: There was a default workflow that was triggering. I have the plugin working now. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Gary Great. Accept the reply as an answer if it helped you (plus I added this particular issue to my trick list). And if you'd recommend it, vote me up. Always nice to get some credit. It was a nasty gotcha, hehe.

Comment: You only need to call the `Update` method on the service if the plugin is a post-operation. If it is pre-operation do not call the `Update` method.