# CRM 2011: error while accesing field names from Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, schema, dynamics-crm

I'm working on a asp mvc project on Visual Studio 2012 that gets data from a CRM 2011 schema.
It's not my first project using CRM as data source, but is the first time I get this error:
*'Account' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'ed_direction'.*

The attribute exists and when I write code the autocomplete function finds it. I try it with most of the attributes and the same thing happends with all. Seems that the code try to find attributes using the name, but the code usually find attributes using the schema name.

Comment: the way to check if the attribute exists is under the customizations, the autocomplete (if you use generated classes) means only that the attribute was present when the classes were cretated, not that the field is still there. Check under customizations

Comment: Also make sure that you are connecting to the correct organization (if you have multiple ones)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about your code... Are you using early binding or late binding? Linq?. Maybe you could supply a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide your code snippet, it would be helpful.

But last week I ran into the same situatuion:

My `account` entity has a `single line of text field:  AccountType` that was not retrieved by the retreive query using `columnset=true` to retrieve all the attributes.

So I found what was the problem:

If `the AccountType` is `NULL` or `Empty` then it was not retrieved,

In entity->attributes->KEY,Value  even the `KEY with the name AccountType` was not showing.

When I filled it with some 'text' then It was retrieved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the attribute has null values and if so it will not be retrieved. Please refer to below link dealing with a similiar issue.

[Using QueryByAttribute cannot retrieve null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088408/using-querybyattribute-cannot-retrieve-null-values)